# How to change the "Date" and "Time" of the mobile phone using "J2ME"?

Tags: java-me, midp, mobile-application, cldc, nokia-s40

I'm developing a mobile application using "J2me" for a configuration "CLDC-MIDP2.0".

In my mobile application, I need to make the user should able to adjust the "Date" and "Time" settings of mobile.

Here I'm using "DateField" to get the date from the user, but I cannot set or change the mobile phone's "Date" and "Time".

How to change the "Date" and "Time" of the mobile phone using "J2ME"? Here I'm using "Nokia c2-00" mobile is for testing. It is "S40" device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do with Java ME. In Java ME, There are so many security features available. For example,

- You can't change the profile.
- You can't read the inbox/outbox SMS.
- You can't access the LOG.
- You can't change the date/time of the mobile.
- You can't change the mobile wallpaper/screen saver.

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found [on this page at Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?13343-How-can-I-set-system-time-in-mobile-using-J2ME)

> Mobiles internal time cannot be changed by Java, because of security
>   features which dont allow access to the native operations.